# Parametric constrained optimization

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I'm new with the Mathematica softwere, so I'm sorry if my request will be stupid.
I have to solve this optimization problem:
[image]

where ps pg and pgs are the variables, and beta,delta and l are parameters with values between 0 and 1. How can I handle with this?

I tried doing this:

```
Minimize[{0.5 (x1 + x2 + x3 (b (1 - a) + 1 - b) + l (1 - b) (1 - g)), 
  x1 - x2 >= b (1 - g) x3 + (1 - b) (x3 + (1 - g) l), x1 >= 0, 
  x2 >= 0, x3 >= 0, 
  x1 - x2 <= b (x3 + (1 - g) l) + (1 - b) (1 - g) x3}, {x1, x2, x3}]
```

but I had no result :(
Thanks everyone for helping me

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean `g` instead of `a` in your code.  Also the help on `Minimize` has the conditions separated by `&&` instead of commas.  It still had trouble not knowing what `b`, `g` and `l` are.  I got it to work with

```
b = .5;
g = .5;
l = .5;

Minimize[{0.5 (x1 + x2 + x3 (b (1 - g) + 1 - b) + l (1 - b) (1 - g)), 
  x1 - x2 >= b (1 - g) x3 + (1 - b) (x3 + (1 - g) l) && 0 <= x1 <= 1 &&
    0 <= x2 <= 1 && 0 <= x3 <= 1 && 
   x1 - x2 <= b (x3 + (1 - g) l) + (1 - b) (1 - g) x3}, {x1, x2, x3}]

(*{0.125, {x1 -> 0.125, x2 -> 0., x3 -> 0.}}*)
```

The solution is probably not unique with b, g, and l unknown.  You will find playing with those values, that there are combinations that have no minimum.

Comment: b ang g are probabilities, so 0<=b<=1 and same for g. I know also that g>b. l is another parameter...I only know that l>0. The solution has to be x2=x3=0 and x1=(1-b)(1-g)l.
The reason is that (copy and paste from the article):
"The problem is one of linear programming. Hence, the solution lies on a vertex of the restricted domain of the program. It can be shown that the restrictions pg>=0,pgs>=0 and ps-pg>=b(1-g)pgs+(1-b)(pgs+(1-g)l) must be binding at the optimum."
thank you for helping me, best regards
PS: why did you put in the constraint that x1,x2,x3<1?

Comment: I assumed they were, but it doesn't change the answer.  I added your assumptions for b, g, and l and they didn't change anything either.